# How to get the following results from multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table's

```
users (PF_NO,NAME_OF_STAFF,DESIGNATION,ROLE,WORKING_STATION,ROLE)
groups(PF_NO,seniority)
holidays(PF_NO,DATE,REASON)
entry(PF_NO,DATE)
```

Basically, I want to print the report below
[image: This is my required report]

So here I want to get details below from multiple tables and the new column `isdone` will contain `Yes` only if a user made an entry for a given date in `holidays` or `entry` table, and `No` if user don't have an entry for a given date in both `holidays` and `entry` table, I want actually to check that user must declare that he is on holiday or do entry.

I tried this myself query below, I'm new in SQL, I know that my query may not be optimal and also not giving desired result

```
select users.NAME_OF_STAFF,users.PF_NO,users.WORKING_STATION ,users.DESIGNATION,groups.seniority,users.role 
from groups,users 
where groups.PF_NO=users.PF_NO 
    AND users.WORKING_STATION=(
        SELECT WORKING_STATION 
        FROM users 
        WHERE PF_NO='1'
    ) 
ORDER by groups.seniority
```

This results in
[image: current]

SO I want to get one more column with `isdone`, So I can check if data entered for today or not, Please help me.

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` with the `holidays` and `entry` tables. Then return `Yes` or `No` depending on whether it finds a match, i.e. whether `holidays.pf_no` and `entry.pf_no` are both null or not.

Comment: Hello, I'm new in SQL, if possible can you do query, I'm learning joins, but its too advance for me

Comment: Can the user have multiple rows in `holidays` or `entry`?

Comment: Yes user will have only one row in one date for holiday (not necessary but not more than one) in entry user can have multiple, but we need to check if he has one record if has then yes if not then no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to test if there are matching rows in `holidays` and `entry`. Since there can be multiple rows in `entry`, join with a subquery that just returns one of them, otherwise you'll get duplicate rows in the result.

```
select u.NAME_OF_STAFF,u.PF_NO,u.WORKING_STATION ,u.DESIGNATION,g.seniority,u.role, 
        IF(h.PF_NO IS NOT NULL OR e.PF_NO IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') AS isDone
FROM users AS u
JOIN groups AS g ON g.PF_NO=u.PF_NO
JOIN (SELECT WORKING_STATION FROM users WHERE PF_NO = '1') AS w ON w.WORKING_STATION = u.WORKING_STATION
LEFT JOIN holidays AS h ON h.PF_NO = u.PF_NO AND h.date = CURDATE()
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PF_NO FROM entry WHERE date = CURDATE()) AS e ON e.PF_NO = u.PF_NO
```

Comment: Hello sir its not checking date anywhere, we have to check entry or holiday for today, I think that's why its not giving expected results

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the question. I edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry to say , its printing no even 1 has entry in holiday and 1 has entry in entry

Comment: Please post some sample data and the desired result. I may be misunderstanding how the two tables should be combined.

Comment: I changed `AND` to `OR`, maybe that's what you want.

Comment: is it okay if I send you db export file?

Comment: No, that's not OK. Post something with just 3-4 users in the question as plain text. Or create a sqlfiddle.

Comment: I created http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24723f/2  Please have a look

Comment: You haven't filled in any of the tables with data.

Comment: I dont know why its not allowing to fill data there, its saying <8000 error

Comment: Your fiddle is too big. Post just a few rows, not everything.

Comment: Hey there sorry for delay, I uploaded some rows in table

Comment: Hey current answer is working now, Have you made any changes?

Comment: I changed `AND` to `OR` like I said before.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm really sorry I checked after you said but that was not working, but its  may be because have 2 tabs open of this question, So maybe I copied the previous one,  But its working now, Thanks again